# If we made a mistake in crontab entry what will happen then

Tags: command-line, cron

If I Made a mistake in the `crontab` entry, like issuing the nonexistent command `coppy` instead of `cp`, what happens upon execution of the task?

Answer (score 3):

First note that, each `cron` job is run in a shell (`sh` i.e. `dash` by default, changeable via the `SHELL` environment variable inside `crontab`). Two cases:

- **`MAILTO` environment variable is set:** A mail will be sent to the mentioned address(es) with the error (STDERR) (and also STDOUT, if any), as if you were run it in the (used) shell
- **`MAILTO` environment variable is null:** Nothing, the error message will be thrown away as no consumer available
- **`MAILTO` environment variable is unset:** The STDERR (and STDOUT if any) will be sent to the local user's mailbox

In all cases, `/var/log/syslog` will have the relevant error message.

---

Note that people often use shell redirections to save the STDOUT/STDERR in a file e.g.:

```
* * * * * your_command >/tmp/cron_msg 2>&1
```

Or if `MAILTO` is set, not to have the STDOUT/STDERR in mail as teh primary intention is to run the command, if so it is a common trend to send to `/dev/null` too:

```
* * * * * your_command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `man 5 crontab`: if `MAILTO` is not defined, "mail is sent to the owner of the crontab." In order to not send mail, `MAILTO` must be defined to be the empty string.